# Windows 7: Clicking a specific given folder should open a program, not open the folder

Tags: windows-7, eclipse

I use Eclipse on a daily basis, and for various reasons it is the easiest to have numerous workspaces for what we do and then open them as needed.

("workspace" is the Eclipse term for a folder with all the individual Eclipse projects in them and it is only used for Eclipse)

Under OS X it is possible to designate a folder as a *package* which launches the corresponding program when clicked as opposed to simply opening the folder in the Finder.  Under Windows 7 clicking a folder, *always* opens it to show the content.

I would like the OS X behavior for these workspace folders under Windows 7 if possible.  (I have a situation in place with a registry entry providing an Open entry in the right-click menu).

Is it possible?  Perhaps just by having a special folder name?

Comment: It is doable in Windows 7, but what should happen exactly when opening such folders apart from launching Eclipse? I guess you meant to load some projects directly, too.

Comment: What about a shortcut which launches Eclipse with the "Start in:" being the folder you want to launch?